# Is there a way to flushall on a cluster so all keys from master and slaves are deleted from the db

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

From the documentation this seems how flushall would work but in practice it is not working that way.  When I use the command `flushall` it only flushes the keys from the db instance the cli is assigned to.

[Redis flushall documentation](https://redis.io/commands/flushall)

> Delete all the keys of all the existing databases, not just the currently selected one. This command never fails.
>
> The time-complexity for this operation is O(N), N being the number of keys in all existing databases.

For example if my cluster redis-cli has started and I search for a key and the node cli changes from 7000 to 7002 corresponding with the key that the hash is located i.e. server 7002 and then do a flush all it will delete the key per that server.

However, the other keys remain.

Is there a way to flushall meaning delete all keys across all masters and slaves?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. You can use the cli's `--cluster` switch with the `call` command - it will execute the provided command on each of the cluster's master nodes (and will replicate, as `FLUSHALL` is a write command, to their respective slaves).

This should do it:

```
$ redis-cli --cluster call --cluster-only-masters <one-of-the-nodes-address>:<its-port> FLUSHALL
```

Comment: It is in the help provided by `redis-cli --cluster help`, but not properly documented on the redis.io website (we're accepting PRs ;))

Comment: one thing that is always a little confusing @itamar is knowing when something is a cli tool and an actual command that can be used live while the cli is active. I'd love to help with documentation as I enjoy using your product

Comment: I just tried this and it happens to execute it on ALL nodes, not only master nodes. replicas too. It requires "--cluster-only-masters" at the end after command.

Comment: @sgohl thanks - updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I had to put `call` before the `--cluster-only-master` flag: `redis-cli --cluster call --cluster-only-masters <one-of-the-nodes-address>:<its-port> FLUSHALL`

Comment: i think the order of arguments is not optimal. it should be:
redis-cli --cluster-only-masters --cluster call ...
else, the current docker.io/redis returns "Unknown --cluster subcommand"